# how to select all the data + joined data in laravel Eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a join query that shows and sorts the hotels based on their discounts on their rooms which is like below :

```php
$direction = $descending ? 'DESC' : 'ASC';
$data = $query->join('accommodation_rooms', 'accommodations.id', '=', 'accommodation_rooms.accommodation_id')
    ->join('discounts', 'accommodation_rooms.id', '=', 'discounts.accommodation_room_id')
    ->select('accommodations.*', 'accommodation_rooms.*', 'discounts.*')
    ->orderBy('discounts.amount', 'desc');
return $data;
```

now this query just picks the hotels that have rooms with a discount and in the end, it sorts them but I want to pick all accommodation and show the ones who have a discount on room first. what I want to do is that I want to get all the accommodations and sort the discount amount if it exists on the room and if nothing happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `leftJoin` to join discounts instead. Left join will include all of the rows in the table you are beginning with and join `null` on non matching rows on your second table.

Comment: This is not an answer. So remove this. And if you want to ask some clarifications, ask them in the comments.

Comment: yes it just solved with changing the secound join to left join so you may edit your answer for people in future to use it thanks